# undefined method `respond_to' for Api::V1::LocationsController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am new to rails and decided to make make an application that shows the weather. I followed this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast) and GoRails Rails API video course. When I run server (path: http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/locations), I see `undefined method respond_to for Api::V1::LocationsController:Class` error. The same is with `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/locations/1`. I googled a lot, but didn't see an appropriate answer. I am leaving code here. Locations is for the city and Recordings is for temperature. I am also leaving schema here if this is the case. [A screen of directories tree is attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kemZl.png)

I'VE NEVER BEEN SO STUCK

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :locations
    end
  end

  resources :locations
  root "locations#index"
end
```

**locations_controller:**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class LocationsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

    def index
      respond_with LocationsController.all
    end

    def show
      respond_with find_location
    end

    private
    def find_location
      @location = LocationsController.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
  end
end
```

**recordings_controller**

```
class RecordingsController < ApplicationController
end
```

**application_controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

**Models:**

**location.rb**

**It is also not able to find these fields in db for some reason...**

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recording 

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

**recording.rb**

```
class Recording < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
end
```

**schema:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_10_20_135036) do
  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "recording_id", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["recording_id"], name: "index_locations_on_recording_id"
  end

  create_table "recordings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "temp"
    t.string "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "locations", "recordings"
end
```

**I thought to use here one-to-many association. As I thought, one city has one temperature and one temperature has loads of cities.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is quite old and partly outdated. The `respond_to` method which is in the first line of the `Api::V1:: LocationsController` was removed in Ruby on Rails 5.0 about six years ago.

But the good news it that its functionality has been extracted to the [responders](https://github.com/heartcombo/responders) gem. That means when you add that gem to your application's `Gemfile` then it might work after running `bundle install` and restarting the server.

Note. I wrote *it might work* because it is possible that there are other incompatibilities between the tutorial and your current, up-to-date Ruby on Rails version 7.0.

Comment: Thank you! I refactored the code to `render json: ...`. The problem was that I was stupid and created instances in locations_controller from LocationsController class, not Location. :)